# Why doesn't my Angular directive work if set inside dialog?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, directive

I have directive for change background color but when set inside dialog no work.

inside dialog:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <h4 class="modal-title" highlightThis [highlightColor]="'orange'" [count]="5">Users</h4>
```

and inside directive:

```
  @Input() count!: number;
  @Input() highlightColor!: string;

  console.log("highlightColor", this.highlightColor);
  this.formSelector.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.highlightColor;
```

NO work..

But when set inside component which is not dialog work...

How to fix this ?

Comment: What is `formSelector`? could you provide the whole source code for the directive?

Comment: Yes.   constructor(
    private formSelector: ElementRef, 
  ) . console.log("highlightColor", this.highlightColor); I call onInit inside directive. @RuslanLekhman

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Nadit, Can you please create a stackblitz repo. for your issue?